# Eurotrip - temporary job for 1 year

Tags: visas, europe, work, long-term

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum validity of a Schengen visa for multiple visits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/maximum-validity-of-a-schengen-visa-for-multiple-visits)

September next year my fiancée is going to UK for 1 year to study English. I can't accompany her with such an investment, but I could if I can find a temporary job. Ideally I'd go learn French in France by self studying, but unfortunately life in this world ain't so simple.

Worst case scenario, I'd go to some place like Germany or Netherlands where I can pay a very cheap English (or hopefully French) course to get the visa to stay in Europe for 1 year (since as a Brazilian I can stay only 3 months as a tourist). We'd stay 6 months or so, meet some weekends and get together somewhere else later for traveling around Europe. That part is easy.

So, any pointers? Can this even be done? Is there any country in Europe I can get such a hassle free temporary work visa? Should I just stay home and visit her later for 3 months? That last option will certainly be doable at least.

Comment: Given that it's different depending on where you're from, we'd need to know your citizenship status...

Comment: @MarkMayo: He has already mentioned Brazilian.

Comment: ah, for some reason my scanning totally missed the non-capitalized word.  Need more coffee.

Comment: Hi Cawas, welcome to Travel.SE. You question covers ground previously asked on this site on validity of Schengen visas, and as you will find, you aren't allowed to stay longer than 90 days in one go on a tourist visa. Additionally, would probably won't be allowed to work either. Immigration-related question are off-topic on Travel.SE but you may express your support for [Immigration.SE proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10331/immigration).

Comment: Also note that a Schengen visa does *not* allow you to enter UK or a UK visa allow your fiance to enter the Schengen area. I feel your pain though, having been in long distance relationships. Hope you can work it out.

Comment: First of all, thanks all for the prompt input! @AnkurBanerjee I was aware of Immigration, but I'm also aware that most Area51 sites don't get to life. And I figured this is not about Immigration, since I'm not trying to stay there. But now I suppose I was wrong. And all that's fine. I'll just keep researching. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkMayo you're probably right I should've capitalized it. I'm just not used to do it.